# slugfield vs. regex - should I add a slug to models?

Tags: django, url, slug

My models don't currently have a slugfield in them. So far, when I use a table value in the url such as `/movie/Gone With The Wind`, I'd just use a regular expression to get the value I want in the url.

```
(r'^movie/(?P<movie_nm>[\w|\W]+)/$', movie_page),
```

So far, this has worked out fine for me.

Is it advisable to go back and add a slugfield? I don't want to go through the hassle as I don't see the downside to the current method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what your data looks like and how pretty you want your URLs to be.  If you have a movie name that has a character other than the `\w` set (including most punctuation), your URL pattern will break.

Also, remember that your titles will need to be URL escaped--if you care about the aesthetics, `/movie/Gone-With-The-Wind` looks a lot better than `/movie/Gone%20With%20The%20Wind`.

Comment: Yes, the version with dashes is what it looks like if you slugify it, making it URL-safe.  If you don't, the spaces will be automatically converted by your browser to `%20`s--try it by plugging it into your location bar.  If you don't URL escape, you have bigger problems waiting--if a title has characters with special meaning, like a `/` or a `?`, then your URLs will be seriously broken.

Comment: It does return "Gone With The Wind" with the spaces. Other values, like a period (.) also return as-is. But, to Michael C. O'Connor's point, a comma (,) returns %20. Is there a list of characters that return and those that don't?

Comment: @jabs, [here's a summary of acceptable characters in URLs](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)--I'm not sure how you're getting a `%20`s for a comma though--that should be encoded as `%2C`.  The bottom line, is that any characters outside the permissible, non-reserved set `[0-9a-zA-Z$-_.+!*'(),]` should be percent-encoded. However, quotes, forward slashes, and question marks will all be very problematic.